# glReadPixels and GL_ALPHA

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to read the alpha pixel values using glReadPixels. The first thing I did was read the pixels individually. To try to speed things up, I tried reading all the pixels at once :

```
GLubyte *pixels = new GLubyte[w*h*4];
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

and it worked, but really slow. Now I'm trying to just retrieve the alpha value, without wasting space to the RGB components :

```
GLubyte *pixels = new GLubyte[w*h];
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); 
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

But I get : `OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]`.

Any idea as to why a `INVALID_ENUM (0x0500)` is thrown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation on glReadPixels() for OpenGL ES](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glReadPixels.html), the only valid enum values for the format parameter are `GL_RGBA` and `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT_OES`.  You'd need to check and see what `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT_OES` means as a format for the iPhone, but it may not provide support for `GL_ALPHA`.

In any case, I doubt that going that route will dramatically speed up your reads, because all that will do is discard the RGB components.  Your performance issues with glReadPixels() probably lie elsewhere.  A good discussion of the reasons for this can be found in the discussion thread [here](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=473794).

Would it be possible for you to render into an offscreen framebuffer that was backed by a texture, then do further processing on the GPU using that texture?  This sounds like it would yield better performance than using `glReadPixels()`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Regarding your last suggestion, do you have any pointers as to how to implement that?

Comment: @sharvey - See my writeup here: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios .  The sample application I have there: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip uses an offscreen framebuffer to render to a texture, although I pull in the result using `glReadPixels()` because I couldn't finish the GPU-based color averaging I wanted.  I ended up using a slower C routine to do this.  I'll complete this at some point.